# How to pass $_POST variables to the same page

Tags: php

I don't see the echo results in the HTML part of this code where I try to echo $_POST variables. I fill out my form. Click submit but nothing appears under the form, but it should show two strings.

It's a one page form that will extract XML data from a URL that I build in this code based on values provided in the form fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['company']) and isset($_GET['from']) and isset($_GET['to']) and isset($_GET['submit'])){
        $parameters = array(
            'company' => $_GET['company'],
            'from' => $_GET['from'],
            'to' => $_GET['to']
        );
        // create condition
        $condition = "date_entered > '" . $parameters['from'] . "' && date_entered < '" . $parameters['to'] . "' && company_name = '" . $parameters['company'] . "'";
        $url = "www.abc.com/c=" . $condition;
        echo '<p>'.$condition.'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$url.'</p>';
        $_GET['condition'] = $condition;
        $_GET['url'] = $url;
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Reports v. 0.0.0.1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script>
            $(function() {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            }
            });
            $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            }
            });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form autocomplete="on" method="GET">
            Company: <input id="company" name="company" type="text" value="" /><br />
            <fieldset width="0px">
            <legend>Date Range</legend>
            <label for="from">From</label>
            <input type="text" id="from" name="from"><br />
            <label for="to">To</label>
            <input type="text" id="to" name="to"><br />
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['condition']) and isset($_GET['url'])){
                echo $_GET['condition'];
                echo '<br />';
                echo $_GET['url'];
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no fields named `url` or `condition` and your form is not set to send form data via POST.

Comment: You're using the `GET` method, so parameters are all in `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: BTW, you can write `isset($foo, $bar, $baz, ...)` instead of calling `isset()` separately for each variable.

Comment: @John Conde 
There aren't? What do I have starting on line 10?

@Barmar
I switched everything to GET, even the `method` of the form but no dice.
Thanks for the isset() tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dump the global $_GET, compare it to what you are checking. That should help.

Comment: What do you mean by dumping?

Comment: var_dump($_GET); or print_r($_GET);

Comment: That displays the debug info though. I just want to echo to see if my form passes values to itself. What I'm wondering is why I don't see simple echos?

Comment: $_GET['submit'] is not set… and it looks like you are going to be posting a few more questions about the rest of your script.

Comment: Yeah, one more question :)

My date is shown in url as mm/dd/yyyy. How to convert that and all of the spaces into url safe format. What I mean is turn all spaces in the url into %20 and all special symbols like /, <, >, &&, == into %(number here) format.

Comment: I would post this as a new question.